# Windows 7 Internet Explorer 8 protected mode issue

Tags: java, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, applet, protected-mode

I developed a Java applet that launches an executable file.

When I launch an executable file using the applet - with "protected mode activated" - my sistem crashes.

If I were to put my website in the trusted sites' list, it would work. 
However, I can't do that because some of the links of my site don't work in this mode.

Does someone know how can I prevent this behavior?

In other words, is it possible to run an executable in protected mode without putting the website in the trusted sites' list?

Thank you very much and best regards.

Answer (score -1):

You cant launch executables from the applet due to security settings. You will have to convert your applet to Web Start app.

Comment: JWS apps. by default are subject to the same security restrictions that apply to applets.  The way to get increased levels of trust is to digitally sign the code (add the appropriate security element to the JNLP file - if it a JWS app.) and induce the user to accept the digitally signed code when prompted at start-up.

Comment: "You will have to convert your applet to Web Start app."  Also wrong, or at least misleading.  JWS could launch applets since Java 1.2, when JWS was first introduced.  Since Sun's 1.6.0_10 'Next Generation' plug-in2, JWS deployed applets could also be embedded in a web page, where previously they had been free floating.  See the [Java Web Start tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for more details & links.

Comment: duh. obviosuly W.s. app will be signed.

Comment: "duh. obviosuly W.s. app will be signed".  Applets can be signed too.  Again, there is no real difference between them that justifies either of the statements in your answer.  There's no squirming out of the fact that your entire information *is just plain wrong.*  You might save yourself some further embarrassment & down-votes by simply deleting the answer.  AFAIU that would make my comments disappear, as well.